# Fatal Error sun.security.validator PKIX path building failed

Tags: tomcat, ssl, java

I have faced this issue earlier and got the work around by updating my JDK. Earlier when I faced this issue I was using default installation which I did using Yum and later I downloaded the JDK from oracle and installed it and changed the default $JAVA_HOME path as per the new installation dir. Now the same issue has re-occurred and I have checked the [related post on the net](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Failure-Fatal%20transport%20error%3asun.security.validator.ValidatorException%3a%20PKIX%20path%20building%20failed%3a%20sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException%3a%20unable%20to%20find%20valid%20certification%20path%20to%20requested%20target&oq=Failure-Fatal%20transport%20error%3asun.security.validator.ValidatorException%3a%20PKIX%20path%20building%20failed%3a%20sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException%3a%20unable%20to%20find%20valid%20certification%20path%20to%20requested%20target&aqs=chrome.0.57.262&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) unable to find any fix.

The sample code which we are using is just simple authentication over http or https.

```
//Http client object
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HostConfiguration config = client.getHostConfiguration();
client.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(100000));


String Url = 'https://example.com/';
PostMethod method = new PostMethod(Url);

//Handler to try for 3 attempt in case of network failure
method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER,
                                                                new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

//Here we are trying to connect through Httpclient method
int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
```

Not sure what is causing the issue.

```
    keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
    Enter keystore password:

    Keystore type: JKS
    Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 76 entries
```

#### Edited on 11-Feb-2013

I did some more testing and re-installed my jdk and tomcat too but still getting the same error.

```
Failure-Fatal transport error:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I followed the instruction given on the [URL](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target) :

```
java InstallCert services.example.com
Loading KeyStore jssecacerts...
Opening connection to services.example.com:443...
Starting SSL handshake...

No errors, certificate is already trusted

Server sent 1 certificate(s):

 1 Subject CN=*.example.com, OU=Domain Control Validated, O=*.example.com
   Issuer  SERIALNUMBER=04343339, CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority, OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US
```

This shows that the certificate is already added to cacerts. Now this is getting more interesting.

Comment: You need to ensure your application is using the correct Java binary. This may be resolved through JAVA_HOME but if it's a system install of Tomcat then a user environment is likely to be ignored. Please give the error you're experiencing

Comment: thanks @Fuzzyfelt for the clue I have resolved the issue it seems. I am still testing it and confirm once I am sure :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally after all the trouble and help from the **members** I got a fix for this issue. I am providing my answer in case in future any one face the same issue.

Server services.example.com was using wild card certificate (in my case) and it was not sending the complete certificate during the SSL handshake (as per my best understanding), which has caused this issue.

To fix such kind of issue we need to add the certificate to java truststore “cacerts”.

1: I downloaded a java code from the URL http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target
I placed this file on the server at location “$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts”

2: I have compiled the code using “javac InstallCerts.java” which created a class file.

3: Then executed the following command to add the certificate for server “services.example.com”

```
java InstallCert services.example.com

Enter certificate to add to trusted keystore or 'q' to quit: [1]
1
```

I entered “1” to add the certificate to trusts tore file “jssecacerts”.

4: Finally I replaced the file “cacerts” with the file “jssecacerts”.  (Note: take the backup of both the files before replacing it)

```
mv cacerts cacerts-bkp-12-Feb-2013
cp –p  jssecacerts cacerts
```

5: Confirm that the certificate has been added to the cacerts file. To confirm it execute the following command:

```
keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts | grep example
Enter keystore password:

services.example.com-1, Feb 12, 2013, trustedCertEntry,
```

6: Restarted related services and tested the issue and it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your truststore doesn't trust the server certificate. Is it self-signed? You may need to export it from the server and into your truststore.

Comment: Yes it is self singed (the certificate installed for my domain) but I am not facing issue with all the Https only with the wild card certificate. I just checked with the URLs for which this issue is occurring and most of them are wild card certificates. Also which certificate I need to export is it the URL for which I am facing the issue and where should I store the exported certificate in my truststore.

Comment: You need to export the certificate of the server that you are contacting when you get this error. Surely that's obvious? And there is no such thing as 'where ... in a truststore'. Your questions are pointless.

Comment: I am not sure about this issue and very new to tomcat and this issue. But the website which we are contacting via our application has a certificate signed from Godaddy. If I need to export the certificate of the server that I am contacting then where I should place it on my server or we need to modify the code to export the certificate also do we need to do this for all the SSL sites.

Comment: So it isn't a self signed certificate at all, so why did you say it was? Let's start all over again, and this time suppose you provide accurate information. Run your client with -Djavax.net.debug=SSL,handshake and edit the output into your question.

Answer (score 1):

So Maybe someone will have this issue which have been a frustrating problem that took me two days to locate and solve. The problem is that the JVM dosen't trust the certificate of the server, so the solution of caurse is to configure our Tomcat server and our JVM to trust this site. so i will mention all the steps to solve the problem :

1. download the certificate of the site by opening its link with firefox, then clicking on the green lock, then more information, then security tab, the view certificate button, then details tab, and finally export button. lets supose it is named server_cert.crt
2. add the certificate to the JVM list of certificates to trust: you should be able to do that by navigating to the C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\security. the file to update is named cacerts, so copy the downloaded certificate server_cert.crt to the folder then open the command line in the same location then execute the command :

> keytool -J-Duser.language=en -import -trustcacerts -alias somealiasexp
>   -keystore cacerts -file server_cert.crt

the password is changeit
you should have a positive confirmation in the command line.
to check that the certificate was added, execute the command :

> keytool -list -keystore cacerts -alias somealiasexp

. and the certificate should be displayed.

3. now lets configure our tomcat server to use the cacerts keystore, go on the folder "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.88\bin" and create the file "setenv.bat" then copy this code inside it :

> set JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/lib/security/cacerts"
>   "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"

4. In the other hand we have to configure a new port or connector for example for ssl which contains the keystore and the certificate, so :
5. create a new folder, for example "C:/tomcatkeystore"
6. enter in the folder and create a new keystore by executing the command on the CMD :

> keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcatkeystore.jks
>   when this command is executed you will gone have to set a password, let supose it is "some_password".

7. if you want to buy a trusted certificate you have to generate a certificat request by executing the command :

> keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -file certtomcat.csr
>   -keystore tomcatkeystore.jks

8. copy the downloaded certificate server_cert.crt in the folder then add it to the generated keystore by executing the command :

> keytool -J-Duser.language=en -import -trustcacerts -alias somealias
>   -keystore tomcatkeystore.jks -file server_cert.crt

9. now lets update the file server.xml located in the folder "C:\Program Files\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.88\conf" by copying this tag :

```html
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
                   maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
                   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
                   keystoreFile="file:///C:/tomcatkeystore/tomcatkeystore.jks" keystorePass="some_password" />
```

10. now the final step is to restart your server
    .

to test if the ssl port is configured correctly you should be able to access the tomcat interface in the link "https://localhost" and add an exception for it. And thats it, i hope that this was helpfull.